# Creating a nicely coded level select screen

Tags: actionscript-3

Currently developing my first full flash game, and I'm now implementing multiple levels, which means I have to make a level select screen. I have no problem with actually accomplishing this, but the only way I know how to do this would be to make a different level select screen available every time somebody passed a new level (ie, after passing level 2, now there are 2 buttons available, for level 1 and 2 instead of just level 1).

Of course, this is highly inefficient. I want to be able to do this for all my levels in one go. I already know in advance that I will be having 9 levels, so a 3x3 grid system of buttons is possible (maybe using 2 for loops, for x and y position?).

Navigating between level select and other pages is no problem, I should be able to do that. My real problem is creating the actual level select screen to display different amounts of clickable buttons depending on how far one has progressed in the game. I mean I'm guessing I just create some boolean values for the user, and once a level is passed I change those booleans to true, then link the boolean to creating a button instead of a static text field. Then would I just position each button individually on the level select screen? If somebody could shed some light ( and by light I mean code =p ) about how to accomplish making this type of level select screen, it would be greatly appreciated, particularly the part about adding the buttons to the stage vs. the textfields.

Also, is it a waste to create 9 different buttons? It would be nice to just create 1 button and then just change the text field on them to display the level number. Can I accomplish this using a dynamic text field and just altering the text in that text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes, you can do whatever you see fit, just prepare for all of this. This is mostly architecture question than actual programming question. About progress, you can either track the highest available level and only display those that are available, or display level progress (say one level was complete with 1 star, the other with 2 stars, and you make buttons with stars on them), etc. Also, you might look at say Angry Birds level selector, it has 15 buttons, why could you not make 9?

About how to add a custom button to stage - first, it's better if you wrap the whole level selector into a Sprite, write AS3 code for it having level buttons placed at specific coordinates, a close button (aka "no I want to review other options before selecting level" one), other data like a text field with level name, etc etc, whatever you see fit. An example (with only level buttons, mostly in pseudocode):

```
public class LevelSelector extends Sprite {
    private static const thumbnailClasses:Array=[Level01Bitmap,Level02Bitmap,...];
    // embed these
    private var gridXOffset:Number=60;
    private var gridYOffset:Number=60;
    private var gridXDimension:int=3; // how many buttons in row
    private var gridXBase:Number=30;
    private var gridYBase:Number=10;
    // other initialized data
    private var buttons:Vector.<LevelButton>; // buttons stored here
    public function LevelSelector() {
        buttons=new Vector.<LevelButton>();
        // other initialization
        for (var i:int=0;i<thumbnailClasses.length;i++) {
            var b:LevelButton=new LevelButton();
            b.x=(i%gridXDimension)*gridXOffset+gridXBase;
            b.y=Math.floor(i/gridXDimension)*gridYOffset+gridYBase;
            b.picture=(new thumbnailClasses[i]()).bitmapData;
            // assuming thumbnails are embedded bitmap class names
            addChild(b);
            b.enabled=levelIsAvailable(i); // query level availability
            b.stars=getLevelPerformance(i); // query how many stars to draw
            b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonPressed); // listen for mouse
            buttons.push(b);
        }
    }
    private function buttonPressed(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var level:int=buttons.indexOf(e.target);
        var b:LevelButton=e.target; // if need to do something with the button
        // query correctness and navigate to level screen
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome response Vesper, a few questions. For the thumbnailClasses, would I have to create a class for every one of these? They're actual level previews right? For the buttons stored part, are you suggesting to create an array/vector of buttons and creating a button for each level? And finally....didn't quite understand the query level availability part...

Comment: your for loop is awesome I love it hehehe

Comment: For thumbnailClasses, yes they are intended to be pre-generated level previews. AKA you start a level, take a screenshot, crop it, resize it, embed it into your SWF and name it `Level01Bitmap`. Some games have level thumbnails made exactly like that. Querying level availability - you can call a static method for this, or you can have a callback assigned that will return a Boolean if provided an int, and a `LevelButton` instance will accept this as its `enabled` property, and for example, not react on mouse clicks - this depends on its implementation.

Comment: About creating buttons for levels, yes I'd advise this, if you want your levels to be selectable by a single click. If there would be dozens of levels, then it'll be better to assign different pictures to buttons (then store those pictures instead of class names in that array `thumbnailClasses`) and have a handful of buttons to be able to select one of a set, and a set out of whole multitude of levels (Angry Birds have sets of 15 to display each time, and you select a level by pressing one of 15 buttons).

Comment: Actually I am advising a rough replica of one of the more suited interfaces that was made by community, and since it works, I din't think you need to invent a worse wheel than this. Another approach (which does not differ in mechanics, but differs in appearance) is having all levels as small buttons arranged over a sort of global map, this requires you to make such a map and align it with storyline, which is extra work and I'm not sure whether you have it or plan to.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I think I understand how to fully make this. For now I will experiment using the bitmap idea because I like it. If it proves to be too much work I'll just stick to a regular button with a different text field.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to break the problem down into smaller steps. I'm not sure if you're using the Flash timeline or external .as Classes. I'd recommend using Classes as you can be much more flexible about what you display on screen. If you're not used to using Classes, the following probably won't make much sense...

In your main Document.as Class you could keep track of which levels the player has completed (perhaps in an Array of Boolean values corresponding to the level numbers). When a LevelSelect page is needed, make a new LevelSelect page and pass the _levelsCompleted Array as a parameter. The passed array can be used by the LevelSelect Class instance to determine how many LevelButtons are needed. Loop through the passed Boolean array and if an index value is true, add a LevelButton. Each LevelButton could be passed its level number (the loop counter) which could be used in its TextField to identify it (remember Array indexes are zero indexed, so level '1' might actually be '0').

If this doesn't make any sense, let me know.

Comment: Yes I'm using classes, ah that makes sense! I like the advice about using the array index value to determine the text field number